# Adding HTML to ruby on rails flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `flash[:success]` message which goes like this:

`flash[:success] = "This text is now bold."`.
However, when I go to make the text bold, it just wraps HTML characters around the message, rather than actually turning bold.

```
<b>This text is now bold</b>
```

How can I go about including HTML into flash messages?

Comment: where and how do you display them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `<%= flash[:success].html_safe %>` in your view.

Whenever your `flash[:success]` is blank, it will show error due to `html_safe`. So it is better to use a condition.

So try with the following to prevent that error:

```
<%= flash[:success].html_safe unless flash[:success].blank? %>
```

You could also use `.try` to prevent that error:

```
<%= flash[:success].try(:html_safe) %>
```

And if you know there is content for sure, you can also try:

```
<%= raw flash[:success] %>
```

## ERB-specific HTML display

On top of that, since you are using ERB, you can use `h()` method for HTML-escaped strings:

```
<%= h flash[:success] %>
```

[Check out this tutorial on ERB for other options such as for displaying JSON or URL-encoded strings.](https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/#using-text-transformation-methods)

Comment: or better yet: `<%= raw flash[:success] %>` (if you know the content is safe)

Answer (score 3):

save message as

```
flash[:success] = "<b>This text is now bold.</b>"
```

put in the html file as

```
<div class="notice">
<%=h flash[:notice]%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add arbitrary HTML to your flash message, but you'll need to user `html_safe` to render it unescaped.

```
flash[:error] = "<em>Crap!</em> We lost everything."
```

In the view:

```
<%= flash[:error].html_safe %>
```