# Render HTML into Rails flash message

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How to render html into Rails flash message/notice ?

I have this `destroy` action from my `UsersController` :

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> Utilisateur supprimé.".html_safe
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

When I call this `destroy` action, the flash success message print the html tag instead of render it.

I have try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747039/adding-html-to-ruby-on-rails-flash-message?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer but I don't how to use it since I am in the controller and not in the view so I am not using <%= %> to embed the code.

Comment: You can just call `.html_safe` inside the flash partial in your ERB file. Just be careful and make sure the flash value is never populated with user inputed content.

ie: `<%= value.html_safe %>`

Comment: In the application layout I have `<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %> ... <% end %>`, I have add `.html_safe` to the message inside the block like this `<%= message.html_safe %>`. But now, it's not printing anything from the html tag, like if it doesn't even exist...

Comment: EDIT : If I put `<b>Test</b>` into my flash message, the word is printed bold. But using `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` to print icon from fontawesome, it's not working... Any idea why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding HTML to ruby on rails flash message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747039/adding-html-to-ruby-on-rails-flash-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone encounter the same problem, here is an answer working for me :

**1st** : the `.html_safe` method has to be applied to the message of the flash as Justin Licata said.

**2nd** : if you want to use icons (Font awesome in my case) into your message, putting it into your message string will not work, you have to put it into your `.html` file which print your flash message. (Inspired from [this](https://gist.github.com/danielRomero/0d50a15b3c9569a2367b))

Here is my rendering flash message code, into my layout `application.html.erb` :

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="row" id="msgContainer">
    <div class="callout callout-<%= message_type %>" id="flash_message">
      <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
      <% end %>
      <% if flash[:danger] %>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      <% end %>
      <% if flash[:success] %>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= message.html_safe %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This work for me, hope this can help.